# what int,float variables after the program is executed

Tags: java, memory

In general, as for as objects, java reclaims the memory occupied by the object whenever it is no longer needed. But at the same time we are using int, float and double data types, which are defined internally by the java language itself. What about the memory of that data type whenever it is no longer needed?

Please give me a reply...

Saravanan.P

Comment: Reformat the question. It looks like you're asking what the memory requirements are for value types as opposed reference types.

Comment: Not sure about the answer I'm going to give. So please correct me if I am wrong. I thought that the garbage collector collects object AND Variables that have no pointers to it. So if u make a variable null the Garbage collector comes and frees the memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java removes any variables from memory as soon as those variables are no longer accessible. In other words, the built-in primitive datatypes consume no memory as soon as you leave the block they were declared in.

The memory usage of the different primitive datatypes are:

```
byte: 8 bit
short: 16 bit
int: 32 bit
long: 64 bit
float: 32 bit
double: 64 bit
boolean: 1 bit (it represents one bit, but can consume up to a byte)
char: 16 bit
```

Comment: "assuming you don't pass a pointer to it to another method, but that is rarely necessary" This is not possible in Java

Answer (score 3):

Primitives (like int, float etc) are allocated in the stack, if they are local method variables and in the heap if they are member variables (i.e. fields of a class). Only the heap is garbage collected.

Comment: A primitive field in an object is allocated on the heap, as part of that object. Only local variables are allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Fields and static variables are initialized to 0. Local variables must be explicitly initialized, otherwise the compiler will report an error.